# Apache 2.4 Heartbeat Flow

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat

I have recently upgraded from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 and am looking into changing the proxy method used by the server from the basic mod_proxy to [mod_lbmethod_heartbeat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.html) in [mod_proxy_balancer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html). I am using an Apache Server as a proxy to send the requests to a number of Tomcat servers, and am unsure of the flow of how the heartbeat method is supposed to work.

My current understanding of the process is the Apache Server should have a [HeartMonitor](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_heartmonitor.html) listening for heartbeat info that will be sent to it by each of the other servers. These servers will have mod_heartbeat so they will know to send the information to the specified port. The Apache Server will then use this information to distribute the requests as best it can. Does this sound like the correct flow for how this method is supposed to work?

If so, how would the mod_heartbeat be loaded onto and used by Tomcat? Both are Apache, but I have not been able to find any documentation on a method like this in Tomcat and that doesn't seem surprising to me since they are different servers and I imagine are implemented very differently. Is there some sort of connector that would let the two communicate in this way, or is mod_lbmethod_heartbeat supposed to only be used between multiple Apache Servers?

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching I found the following [thread](https://lists.gt.net/apache/dev/408496) which seems to indicate that the heartbeat load balancing method was designed only to be used to balance traffic among multiple httpd servers. The correct way to communicate information like this between httpd and tomcat servers seems to be by using mod_jk.